# Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following code which repeats and displays the items of cart.

```
<div ng-repeat="retailer in cart.getOrderedByRetailer()" >
      <ion-item>
        {{retailer.retailer_name}}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-icon-right canasta-item canasta-height" ng-repeat="cartitem in retailer.order_items">
    {{cartitem.stockitem.product.name| limitTo: 20}}
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

With the following method I try to order the items in my cart  but i cant do it

getOrderedByRetailer: function(){

```
        var ordered_order_items = this.content.items.reduce(function (map, obj) {

            if (map[obj.stockitem.retailer] === undefined) {
                //console.log(map[obj.stockitem.retailer]);
                map[obj.stockitem.retailer] = {
                    'retailer_name': obj.stockitem.retailer,
                    'order_items': []
                }
            }

            map[obj.stockitem.retailer].order_items.push(obj);
            //console.info(map);

            return map;
        }, {});

        return ordered_order_items

    }
```

When I run the above code, I get the Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! error in my console.

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong here? Much appreciate your help.

Comment: `ng-repeat="retailer in cart.getOrderedByRetailer()"` That's your problem. Don't bind it to a function, but to a property of the scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is whenever `getOrderedByRetailer()` is executed, it's result is considered by `angularjs` as new one, even it *looks like* previous result. It is [common problem](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig), when your function returns array. So, if result of function depends on only `this.content.items` you can refactor your code this way:

```
<div ng-repeat="retailer in cart.getOrderedByRetailerResult" >
    ....
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
this.content.items = [];
//each time this.content.items are changed call getOrderedByRetailer():
this.cart.getOrderedByRetailerResult = getOrderedByRetailer();
```